# e4x: simplest way to tell if an attribute exists

Tags: javascript, xml, e4x

What's the simplest way to tell if an attribute exists?

```
p = <abc name="foo" />;


js>p.@name.length()
1
js>p.@zebra.length()
0
```

I can use `@attr.length()` but was wondering if there is an `isAttributePresent()` or something.

**NOTE**: This is not in a browser, this is just a javascript interpreter based on core Mozilla Javascript 1.8 with E4X enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
'@name' in p
```

This will return `true` or `false` depending on existence of said attribute.